# Java - Custom class ArrayList has no add method

Tags: java

ArrayList of custom class has no .add() method:

I can define an ArrayList of Object's:

```
ArrayList<Object> thing = new ArrayList<Object>();


thing.add(otherThing); // works
```

However, when I define a list of a custom class Thing:

```
ArrayList<Thing> thing = new ArrayList<Thing>();


thing.add(otherThing); // error


Canvas.java:33: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method add(java.lang.Object)
location: class java.util.ArrayList<Thing>
            thing.add(otherThing);
                   ^
1 error
```

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: How is `otherThing` declared?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `otherThing` must be of the type `Thing`. Currently its of the type `Object`, and that's why it worked for the first case, but failed in the second case.

In your first case, the `ArrayList<Object>` takes elements of type `Object`. Since the `otherThing` is of the type `Object` too, and so it works.

In the second case, the `ArrayList<Thing>` takes elements of type `Thing`. Since, your `otherThing` is still of the type `Object`, whereas it should have been of the type `Thing`, you get that error.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Thing> thing = new ArrayList<Thing>();
```

For this you can only add types of/instances of Thing only other than that is not allowed as its violates Java Generic guideline.

```
ArrayList<Object> thing = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

as here you are specifiying Object and as Object is super class it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

`otherThing` is not declared as `Thing` but an `Object`.